# Getting an array into jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to send an array through a jQuery function and have it animate each of the words in an array.

```
var foo = [];

foo[0]= "test1";
foo[1]= "test2";
foo[2]= "test3";

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".ansy").click(function(){ 

    $.each(foo,function(){

      $('.message').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
        $(this).text("enter text or variable here");
      }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);

    });
  }); 

});
```

I'm using a block of code I got from another place on stackoverflow that works when I replace the "enter text or variable here" with what ever text I want but can't make go through an array. I've been trying to use the $.each function but I haven't been able to get it to work. The idea is to have a string fade in and then fade out and then have the next string in the array fade in and so on until it reaches the end of the array. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, wrap the language construct `array` in a jQuery object so you get the methods of a jQuery Object:

`$(foo)`

Then use `.each` on your new jQuery `array`:

`$(foo).each(function(`

Make sure your function is passing the `index` and `value` parameters:

`$(foo).each(function( i, v ){});`

Then do your animations:

```
$( foo ).each(function( i, v ){
    $('.message')
        .animate({
            'opacity': 0
            },
            2000,
            function(){
                $(this).text(v);
            }
        )
        .animate({
            'opacity': 1
            },
            2000
        );
});
```

Notice I used `v` as the text value.

Be warned, `.text()` and `.html()` do different things.  People usually want `.html()` unless they have a very specific reason for using `.text()`.  Keep that in mind in case you run into any issues.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `$.each(foo,function(i,v)...` similar to what the OP started with? You don't need to wrap `foo` in a jQuery object.

Comment: Purely a matter of preference.  I like my `dot` operators to act on their parent object.  It essentially boils down - in my mind - to making my code read like a story.

Comment: Fair enough, as long as `foo` is an array: if `foo` is a non-array object then `$.each(foo,...` will iterate over its properties but `$(foo).each(...` will not. (Also `$.each()` is more efficient since it is one less function call.)

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
var foo = [];

    foo[0]= "test1";
    foo[1]= "test2";
    foo[2]= "test3";

    $(document).ready(function(){

         $.each(foo,function(){
            var temp = this;
            $('.message').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {
            $(this).text(temp);
           }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);
    }); 


    });​
```

And the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaQkg/)

Comment: I spent a couple of hours trying to fix this and couldn't. So I decided to post a question on here because I can't figure it out. Not five minutes after I post the question I stumble on the answer. Here is how I did it but thanks Mash. Your way might be better.

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mAQy3/)

```
var foo = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]; //add them all to array at same time

$(document).ready( function() {

    $(".ansy").click( function() {

        $.each(foo, function(index, value) {

            $('.message').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000, function () {

                $(this).text( value );

            }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 2000);
        });
    }); 
});
```

See the documentation on [jQuery's `$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for details on its usage.